# How do you navigate to the apparently super secret exchange sites?

Tags: discussion, websites

How do you navigate to the apparently super secret exchange sites?
For instance UX, CodeReview, etc...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a full list of Stack Exchange sites at http://stackexchange.com/sites.

Comment: Thanks, That is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 6):

In addition to what others added, there is a site directory on the drop-down StackExchange inbox as pictured:

[image]

This list is also ordered by reputation, once you have more than 200 rep on a given site.

Answer (score 5):

Those sites are still in beta so don't appear in the footer.

User Experience is on https://ux.stackexchange.com/

Code Review is on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Once you've got there you can see all the other beta sites in their footer.

You can see all the current beta sites at [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/?tab=beta)

Comment: I often wonder if those beta sites will stay beta for a long time, just due to not being linked in the footer along with the "real" sites.